# Error in BufRead settings - number required after =? Multiple solutions tried

Tags: vim

I'm having an issue with the following BufRead commands - I get an error that a number is required after tabstop= (of course there is one there).

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
        \ set tabstop=4|
        \ set softtabstop=4|
        \ set shiftwidth=4|
        \ set textwidth=79|
        \ set expandtab|
        \ set autoindent|
        \ set fileformat=unix
```

Previously on line 2 I had:

```
\ set tabstop = 4
```

(note the spaces) which would cause the error, but changing that didn't seem to help. I've also tried this without the bars but I'm told that's necessary if I want to split the commands over multiple lines for readability. I've also tried putting all the set commands in a  single line a la:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4...
```

All give me the same error. What am I doing wrong? I've exhausted my ability to research this problem.

edit-clarity

Comment: You're probably looking at the wrong code but it's hard to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: Does this example not meet that criterion? A _gvimrc file with just my posted content replicates this behavior for me. Does it not for you?

Comment: Your post doesn't say anything about a `_gvimrc`. That's new information.

Comment: No, it doesn't replicate. It put that content in a file called `_gvimrc`. Vim opens it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax (without the spaces around `=`) is correct. You failed to give the exact Vim version, a minimal example (e.g. `$ vim --clean --cmd "au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4" -c "new foo.py"`, with which I've also failed to reproduce the issue, in Vim 8.0.1358), nor the full error message. I can't help you with that. If you're desperate, you can try the alternative syntax `let &tabstop = 4 | let &softtabstop = 4 | ...`.

However, if you put this code into `_gvimrc` (as indicated in the comments), there is a better way: **Leverage the built-in *filetype detection* and *filetype plugins*.** Put the settings (as `:setlocal`, so that it only affects the *current* buffer) into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`. (Or equivalent for Windows. This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`.)

Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType python ...` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations. `~/.gvimrc` should be used only for GUI-specific initializations; changing indent settings isn't one of those. Even if you exclusively use GVIM, `.vimrc` (or `_vimrc` on Windows) is still read; cp. `:help initialization`.